# Close map info window on click if open

Tags: jquery, google-maps

How can I write an if statement that checks if the infowindow is open, and if so closes it when it or another marker is clicked. My code is below!

```
function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

// var
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

// create marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position    : latlng,
    map         : map
});

// add to array
map.markers.push( marker );

// if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
if( $marker.html() )
{
    // create info window
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content     : $marker.html()
    });

    // show info window when marker is clicked
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

        infowindow.open( map, marker );

    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code in the question, it would be something like this, though it is untested :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var map = infoWindow.getMap();
    if (map !== null && typeof map !== "undefined") {
        infowindow.close();
    } else {
        infowindow.open( map, marker );
    }
});
```

Comment: Gave it a try but still fails to open the marker initially, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Steven_Harris_ - that's probably because `if (infowindow) ...` is failing, edited the answer, try that instead.

Comment: I've added my full function for adding the markers to the map to the question if that helps. I've tried your updated answer but it still isn't opening the info window initially. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
function fun_name() 
{
  //create the global instance of infoWindow 
  if(!window.infowindow)
  {
    window.infowindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  }
    -------
    -------
    -------

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    infowindow.setContent(box_html);
    infowindow.open(map,this)
  });

}
```

Comment: It isn't opening the info window on click.